# How to position elements next to each other in CSS without using float. i.e. main content next to sidebar

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, css-grid

I have a sidebar. I have main content. I want to position my main content div next to my left side bar. My main content div is in the form of a CSS-grid layout. I determined the grid will be best to contain the information I need to display, depicted by a mock-up I was given. I was exploring the option of making the entire HTML page a grid, but I am unsure how to tackle this. So, I figured I will make create a div for my side bar and make it stay there while my main content, the grid, will move around that. But to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scratch.css">
</head> 
  <style>
    body {
      background: darkgrey;
      height: 1000px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .side-bar {
      background: red;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 202px;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .side-bar p{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;

    }

    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      background: #E1E1E1;
      height: 500px;
      width: 1100px;
      grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px 250px;
      grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
      grid-gap: 30px 20px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 25px 0 30px;
      justify-content: right;
      align-content: center;
      position: relative;
      left: 400px;
    }

    .grid-items {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .grid-item1 {
      background: greenyellow;
    }

    .grid-item2 {
      background: rosybrown;
    }

    .grid-item3 {
      background: cadetblue;
    }

    .grid-item4 {
      background: darkturquoise;
    }

    .grid-item5 {
      background: darkkhaki;
      grid-column: span 2;
    }

    .grid-item6 {
      background: lightblue;
      grid-column: span 2;
    }
  </style>
  <body>

    <div class="side-bar">
      <p>Side Bar</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-items grid-item1">
        <p>Grid Item 1</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-items grid-item2">
        <p>Grid Item 2</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-items grid-item3">
        <p>Grid Item 3</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-items grid-item4">
        <p>Grid Item 4</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-items grid-item5">
        <p>Grid Item 5</p>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-items grid-item6">
        <p>Grid Item 6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to have a main grid that contains the sidebar and a grid inside it that contains the main content:

```css
body,
html {
  background: darkgrey;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#horizontal-menu {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#horizontal-menu p {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}

.side-bar {
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.grid-items-container {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px 20px;
  background: #E1E1E1;
  padding: 15px;
}

.side-bar p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-items {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grid-item1 {
  background: greenyellow;
}

.grid-item2 {
  background: rosybrown;
}

.grid-item3 {
  background: cadetblue;
}

.grid-item4 {
  background: darkturquoise;
}

.grid-item5 {
  background: darkkhaki;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-item6 {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-menu">
  <p>Menu</p>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="side-bar">
    <p>Side Bar</p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-items-container">

    <div class="grid-items grid-item1">
      <p>Grid Item 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-items grid-item2">
      <p>Grid Item 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-items grid-item3">
      <p>Grid Item 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-items grid-item4">
      <p>Grid Item 4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-items grid-item5">
      <p>Grid Item 5</p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-items grid-item6">
      <p>Grid Item 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so this looks good but, a reason why i didn't want to put a grid in a grid is because looking at the mock-up, which I can not show unfortunately, I will also need a top information bar that runs horizontally 100% across the top. in addition, I did not want the smaller inner grid to take up the entire right side of the screen, the design as a lot of whitespace. and the grid should only take up the size that i specified in the question

Comment: @EnhancedBot Having a horizontal scroll bar that runs 100% along the top shouldn't be a problem. This can just be added outside the main grid. I will also adjust the inner grid so that it doesn't take up the entire space.

Comment: @EnhancedBot As a side note, it's not a good idea to specify widths like 200px because people may have smaller or larger monitors and the content would be all messed up. Using percentages, or `fr` in grid is a better way of doing it.

Comment: ok, as the code stands right now, will the dimensions cause any problems if run on smaller screen as you say? for example i am viewing this on a laptop 4k on chrome browser. as the code stands, will it look distorted on a browser at 1920x1080. I know this is a tough question to answer 100%

Comment: @EnhancedBot CSS grid is responsive and so it should work at different resolutions. One way of looking is resizing your browser window

Comment: I know i'm not supposed to say thanks here but F-it, thank you!

Comment: @EnhancedBot Not a problem!

Comment: This is best approach. Upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use for div `display: table-cell;`

```css
body {
  background: darkgrey;
  height: 1000px;
}

.right-content,
.side-bar {
  display: table-cell;
}

.side-bar {
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.side-bar p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.right-content {
  width: 70%;
  
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  padding:10px;
  background: #E1E1E1;
  height: 500px;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px 250px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
  grid-gap: 30px 20px; 
  margin: 0 25px 0 30px;
  justify-content: right;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-items {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grid-item1 {
  background: greenyellow;
}

.grid-item2 {
  background: rosybrown;
}

.grid-item3 {
  background: cadetblue;
}

.grid-item4 {
  background: darkturquoise;
}

.grid-item5 {
  background: darkkhaki;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-item6 {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scratch.css">
</head>


<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="side-bar">
      <p>Side Bar</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right-content">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-items grid-item1">
          <p>Grid Item 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-items grid-item2">
          <p>Grid Item 2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-items grid-item3">
          <p>Grid Item 3</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-items grid-item4">
          <p>Grid Item 4</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-items grid-item5">
          <p>Grid Item 5</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-items grid-item6">
          <p>Grid Item 6</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I will try this... and get back to you

Comment: you can run this snippet here

Comment: this provided more headache as now I will need to resize everything I already sized

Comment: can you tell what is desire output ?

Comment: i added changes only. Width i given in percentage that you change to fixed but you have to write media query. @EnhancedBot

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scratch.css">
</head>

<style>
    html,body {
        background: darkgrey;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .side-bar {
        background: red;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 202px;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        display: block;
    }

    .side-bar p {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

    }

    .main-content {
        display: block;
        height: 500px;
        width: 1100px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 203px;
    }

    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        height: 500px;
        width: 1100px;
        background: #E1E1E1;
        grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px 250px;
        grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
        grid-gap: 30px 20px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 25px 0 30px;
        justify-content: right;
        align-content: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .grid-items {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .grid-item1 {
        background: greenyellow;
    }

    .grid-item2 {
        background: rosybrown;
    }

    .grid-item3 {
        background: cadetblue;
    }

    .grid-item4 {
        background: darkturquoise;
    }

    .grid-item5 {
        background: darkkhaki;
        grid-column: span 2;
    }

    .grid-item6 {
        background: lightblue;
        grid-column: span 2;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class="side-bar">
        <p>Side Bar</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-items grid-item1">
                <p>Grid Item 1</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-items grid-item2">
                <p>Grid Item 2</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-items grid-item3">
                <p>Grid Item 3</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-items grid-item4">
                <p>Grid Item 4</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-items grid-item5">
                <p>Grid Item 5</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-items grid-item6">
                <p>Grid Item 6</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Absolute positioning is one option you may want to try. Not sure how much responsiveness you want on your page.

Comment: I am testing this now....responsiveness is not imperative as this design will only run on a desktop browser. the party does not intend to use this interface on mobile, though I am open to that for the sake of learning.

Comment: If its just desktop browser then your approach seems okay.